# How do i correctly form a post request in groovy using httpbuilder

Tags: groovy

I know this question has been asked before and i've been looking for the past few days into how to correctly do this in groovy, but i'm not having any luck. I can do it just fine using postman.

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper

def remote = new HTTPBuilder("https://jira.company.com/rest/com-spartez-ephor/1.0")
remote.request(POST) { req ->
    uri.path = "/workflow/jira/issue/16600/link/TS-6825"
    headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    headers.'Authorization' = 
                "Basic ${"uuuu:pppp".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()}"

    response.success = { resp, json ->
        json ?: [:]
    }
}
```

any help getting this going would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using [HttpBuilder-NG](https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/asciidoc/html5):

```
  implementation 'io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-core:1.0.4'
```

your code could look like:

```
import static groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder.configure
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentTypes.JSON

def remote = configure {
  request.uri = 'https://jira.company.com/rest/com-spartez-ephor/1.0'
  request.contentType = JSON[ 0 ]
  request.auth.basic 'uuuu', 'pppp'
}

remote.post { req ->
  request.uri.path = "/workflow/jira/issue/16600/link/TS-6825"
  response.success { resp, json ->
    println json
  }
  response.exception { t ->
    println t
  }
}
```